# If a switch matches multiple cases will all matching cases run?

Tags: php, switch-statement, bit-manipulation

I'm attempting to go through a large number bitwise tests, 32 to be exact, where there could be multiple matches. The only method I can think of that would work is to use a whole long list of if statements, e.g.

```
$test = 3;
if(($test & 1) == 1) {
    do something...
}
if(($test & 2) == 2) {
    do something else...
}
```

The other possibility I was thinking of to cut down on the code, although probably not by much is a switch statement. That said, I'm not even sure if what I am thinking of will even work:

```
$test = 3;
switch($test) {
    case ((1 & $test) == 1):
        do something...
        break;
    case ((2 & $test) == 2):
        //Will this run?
        do something else...
        break;
}
```

Will the `break` end the switch? Or will the switch continue and each case run that the bitwise operation returns true?

I ask because my actual program will have 32 different tests, and I don't want to write all 32 just to find it doesn't work and Google hasn't turned up anything on this.

If this doesn't work is there a solution that will, or am I relegated to a large number of if statements?

Comment: @Jimbo Hah, yes, it is. Ty and updated.

Comment: This is an unusual use of switches. Checkout the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @Jim I've used switches many times before. I guess this is more of an xy issue. I'll update my original question.

Comment: I've updated my question to include my original intention.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least comment why so I can improve.

Comment: I downvoted because this is something that would take 30 seconds to check.

Comment: @Jim and since I changed my question to make it more expansive so it's not just asking about the switch? Do you still think it deserves the -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not the case. Only one of the switch cases will run in your example. As soon as `break` is encountered the switch processing ends. Only one branch will match. In PHP I think (but you might want to double check) the first matching case will run.

With multiple possible matches you will need to use a set of `if` statements (note do not use if...elseif)

I would convert to

```
if($test & 1) {
    // do stuff
}

if(test & 2) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first, using switch with `int` this way is not really recommended. It's not a good practice / not really readable / not comfortable. I would say it does not even work, although I have a doubt now... depending on versions and stuff, I'm not aware enough of these things.

Then, to answer your question, you only go inside the first matching case... then the **break** makes you **leave the switch**. However, you can **omit the break** and it will go through the second case.

Anyway, you should make more use of OOP to characterize better what you intend to do, and things will probably get more simple and clearer.